# Label Not In List and KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get the value of a specific cell.

```
  main_id   name  code
  0    1345  Jones    32
  1    1543   Jack    62
  2    9874   Buck    86
  3    2456   Slim    94
```

I want the cell that says code=94, as I already know the main_id but nothing else.

```
raw_data = {'main_id': ['1345', '1543', '9874', '2456'],
        'name': ['Jones', 'Jack', 'Buck', 'Slim'],
        'code': [32, 62, 86, 94]}

    df=pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['main_id', 'name', 'code'])


    v=df.loc[str(df['main_id']) == str(2456)]['code'].values
    print(df.loc['name'])
```

The `print(df.loc['name'])` claims the label is not in index

And the `v=df.loc[str(df['main_id']) == str(2456)]['code'].values` says 'KeyError False'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`df.loc['name']` raises a KeyError because `name` is not in the *index*; it is in the *columns*. When you use `loc`, the first argument is for index. You can use `df['name']` or `df.loc[:, 'name']`.

You can also pass boolean arrays to `loc` (both for index and columns). For example,

```
df.loc[df['main_id']=='2456']
Out:
   main_id  name    code
3  2456     Slim    94
```

You can still select a particular column for this, too:

```
df.loc[df['main_id']=='2456', 'code']
Out:
3    94
Name: code, dtype: int64
```

With boolean indexes, the returning object will always be a Series even if you have only one value. So you might want to access the underlying array and select the first value from there:

```
df.loc[df['main_id']=='2456', 'code'].values[0]
Out:
94
```

But better way is to use the `item` method:

```
df.loc[df['main_id']=='2456', 'code'].item()
Out:
94
```

This way, you'll get an error if the length of the returning Series is greater than 1 while `values[0]` does not check that.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, very helpful.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but there is a speedier way to get first you need to set main_id as an index of the dataframe and then you can do this df.loc['2456'] and it is much faster than the approach suggested in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

```
In [76]: df.set_index('main_id').at['2456','code']
Out[76]: 94
```